# vim syntax files under windows vista+?

Tags: windows-vista, vim

In *nix, vim syntax files are in ~/.vim/syntax/[language].vim
But on windows dot is not a welcome folder name start, so it suppose to be _vim\syntax\[language].vim
I have tried putting language files in such folder, but :set syntax=[language] does nothing on windows vista :(. Surprisingly, _vimrc works fine. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under windows vista+ vim keeps syntax files not in %USERPROFILE%.vim\syntax and not in %USERPROFILE%_vim\syntax but in %USERPROFILE%\vimfiles\syntax

Answer (score 1):

In Windows it's perfectly permissible to start folder names with a "." For example looking in an example tree downloaded using SVN there are dozens of folders called ".svn".

JR

Reply to Eye of Hell:

Try opening a command prompt and you'll find you can do

```
c:\test>md .afolder
c:\test>dir .afolder
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ACA6-4A59

 Directory of c:\test\.afolder

24/06/2009  17:59    <DIR>          .
24/06/2009  17:59    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  41,312,174,080 bytes free
```

However having just tried to create a folder called ".afolder" in Explorer, you're quite correct! That seems rather silly design by MS. Nevertheless, this is just an Explorer limitation and names starting with a dot are perfectly legal.

JR

Comment: It's kind of special that can be created only via API, not from windows explorer.

Comment: See my reply. You live and learn :-) Of course real nerds use the command line!

Comment: You live and learn. Thank you a lot, i was sure it's only available via ::CreateFileW() :).